# Calling Azure AD secure functions from Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I recently secured my azure functions by Azure Active Directory. Hence you need access token set in auth header to enable you to call them. I am successfully able to do that from my Front end Angular apps. But in my backend I have Azure Data factory as well, How can i enable Azure Data factory to use Azure AD while calling functions and not host key?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the web activity to get the bearer token and then pass this to the subsequent calls .

Comment: - But to get this token, how will I authorize user? and who is the user here. I am expecting Azure AD User to be used

Comment: You need to create a client ID and Client secret , please follow is article and it should  help  
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-azure-active-directory-application

Once you have the cleintid and the secret you can use that to get the bearer token . The below article should also help 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-rest-api#create-a-data-factory

Answer (score 0):

Azure Data Factory supports Managed Identity:

[Managed identity for Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-service-identity)

> When creating a data factory, a managed identity can be created along with factory creation. The managed identity is a managed application registered to Azure Activity Directory, and represents this specific data factory.
>
> Managed identity for Data Factory benefits the following features:
>
> - Store credential in Azure Key Vault, in which case data factory managed identity is used for Azure Key Vault authentication.
> - Connectors including Azure Blob storage, Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1, Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2, Azure SQL Database, and Azure SQL Data Warehouse.
> - Web activity.

Comment: I have the func app with AzureAD Authetication enabaled and I have setup the ADF with Managed Identities to call the REST API of the func app but it gives me access denied.

Comment: what is the audience of the token ? Did you grant permission to the managed identity to access the function app ?

Comment: Is it a 401 or 403 ? if you could post your own question with relevant details it it will be great

Comment: Thank you @Tomas, nevermind, I figured it out, yes it was the mismatch of a slash in the Audience!